# Get output from intermediate chains in SimpleSequentialChain

Tags: openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, py-langchain

I am using SimpleSequentialChain from langchain.chains
https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chains/langchain.chains.sequential.SimpleSequentialChain.html

When I run the chain, I can see output from each chain but, I can only export the output of the final chain (actionables_chain).

Can someone help me with how to store and export the output from the intermediate chain (summarization_chain)?

Thanks so much!

At the bottom of this code is the SimpleSequentialChain output.  When I try to write the overall_chain_output to csv, it only gets the results from the second paragraph (actionables_chain).  I would also like to export the results from summarization_chain.

Here is my code so far:

```
import openai
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chains import SimpleSequentialChain

llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106", 
                 temperature=0,
                 openai_api_key = "MY-API-KEY")

loader = CSVLoader(Instructor3.csv")
reviews = loader.load()

summarization_template = """
    You are an analyst at a university. 
    You are using qualitative course evaluations to learn about the student experience in this course.
    Summarize the comments made in the attached course evaluations into 1 short paragraph.  
    Here are the comments:
    {comments}
    """
summarization_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(summarization_template)
summarization_chain = LLMChain(llm = llm, prompt = summarization_prompt)

actionables_template = """
    You are a dean of a college.
    You have been given a summary students' experience in a course and need to make recommendations.
    Your recommendations should be in 1 short paragraph and focus on the student experience.
    Acknowledge both areas of success, and areas that need improvement.
    Here is the summary:
    {summary}
    """
actionables_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(actionables_template)
actionables_chain = LLMChain(llm = llm, prompt = actionables_prompt)

overall_chain = SimpleSequentialChain(chains = [summarization_chain, actionables_chain], verbose = True)
overall_chain_output = overall_chain.run(reviews)

file_path = "recommendations_dean.txt"
with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(overall_chain_output)
```

This is the SimpleSequentialChain output.

Entering new SimpleSequentialChain chain...

The course evaluations indicate that students found the course disorganized and difficult, with lectures being unhelpful and based on outdated recordings. The exams were described as challenging, and the professor's reliance on 2019 lectures and lack of live instruction were noted as significant drawbacks. Some students also mentioned that the textbook and practice exams were helpful for preparing for the tests.

Based on the student feedback, it is clear that there are areas in the course that need improvement. The disorganization and reliance on outdated recordings for lectures are significant drawbacks that should be addressed. It is positive to note that the textbook and practice exams were helpful for preparing for the tests, and this should be continued. Moving forward, it is recommended that the course be restructured to include more up-to-date and live instruction to enhance the overall student experience.

Finished chain.